# Problems installing pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to install and run pygame using the text editor Sublime Text and python 3 (I think).  I've tried installing several times and am still getting the following error message from ST when I try and import pygame:

```
import pygame
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/Hank/Desktop/python_work/Chapter_12_alien_invasion/test1.py", line 1, in 
>       import pygame
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
>   [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
>   [cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/python3', '-u', '/Users/Hank/Desktop/python_work/Chapter_12_alien_invasion/test1.py']]
>   [dir: /Users/Hank/Desktop/python_work/Chapter_12_alien_invasion]
>   [path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

I followed this tutorial: http://brysonpayne.com/2015/01/10/setting-up-pygame-on-a-mac/

The relevant command is here:

```
sudo pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

But even though I use 'sudo', I still get this message:

> The directory '/Users/Hank/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>   The directory '/Users/Hank/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

I'm sorry - I know many people ask this question, but I am just clueless what to do now.  Thank you for your help.

This is the error message I receive when I try `pip3 install --user  hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`:

Failed building wheel for pygame

Here is a link to the full text of the message I receive after trying to install:

https://pastebin.com/hZKU8VUZ

Comment: "I've tried installing several times" doesn't help us debug the problem unless you tell us _how_ you installed it.

Comment: Have you installed pygame into your python folder? If not, do the following: first make sure python is on `path`, now in your command line you need to type `python -m pip install pygame`. This depends on your OS, but the point is that you need to have pygame in your python folder installed using `pip`

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://brysonpayne.com/2015/01/10/setting-up-pygame-on-a-mac/

Comment: also just edited the original question to include info about how it was installed

Comment: That tutorial really shouldn't be having you `sudo pip3` in a brew-installed Python. And that's exactly why you're getting those warning you mention at the end. I don't _think_ it should break the install, but… maybe try without that? You may need to `brew uninstall python3` then `brew install python3` before you can `pip install` anything properly.

Comment: @Leaozinho I would try: `pip install pygame --user`

Comment: Meanwhile, the paths being displayed don't seem to come from a Homebrew Python in the first place. Did you by any chance install Python 3.7 using an installer from python.org, and then install another Python 3.7 from Homebrew?

Comment: @abarnert - I did do exactly that.  What should I do to counteract it?

Comment: @Leaozinho Assuming you don’t actually want/need two versions of Python 3.7: uninstall both, reinstall the one you want to keep, then do the `pip install` without `sudo`, and hopefully you’ll be fine. If not, there may be some extra stuff you need to clean up, but cross your fingers that there isn’t.

Comment: @Abarnert, just tried this and am still getting the 'no module called 'pygame'' message

Comment: You installed it with `pip3 install pygame`? OK, please show us the output of these commands: `python3 --version`, `pip3 --version`, `pip3 list -v |grep pygame`

Comment: @abarnert:
python3 --version: Python 3.7.0
pip3 --version: pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
pip3 list -v |grep pygame: no output (?)

Comment: I get what looks like a lot of errors when I try this command:    `pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`
it's too long a message to include in here, how should I post it ?

Comment: Here's something: when I run python 2.7 in terminal I CAN import pygame.  Can someone help me understand what this means and how I can get pygame to run with python3?

Comment: Well, if `pip3 install` failed, that's why you don't have it installed, and that's what you have to fix. If the errors are too long to [edit] into your question, try to at least guess which parts are important (if you have no clue, the beginning and end are usually good chances) and edit them in, and then put a link to a gist or pastebin with the full error output right next to that.

Comment: Thank you - I just created a pastebin link in the original question.

Comment: The second message you have is not an error, it's a warning -- meaning you can simply ignore it.

Comment: what about the 'failed building wheel' part?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the latest version of python3
2. Open the terminal
3. Enter: 
   "python3 -m pip install Pygame == 1.9.4" (Currently latest version)
4. Write "import pygame" on IDLE and run it to check that pygame works fine

Answer (score 0):

I also entered almost the same line: `python3 -m pip install Pygame` on the terminal. Then I entered `import pygame` on Jupyter QtConsole and it responded the following lines:

```
pygame 1.9.5
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

Then, I tried on Jupyter Notebook and it's working too. I am using `Python 3.7.1`.